# how to compare every picklist value of industry with other picklist value

Tags: apex

```java
Schema.DescribeFieldResult industryField = Account.Industry.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = industryField.getPicklistValues();
string otherVal = 'Finance'

for(Schema.PicklistEntry picklistValue : picklistValues){
    system.debug('picklistValue--> ' +picklistValue);
    if(picklistValue.getValue().contains(otherVal) {
        system.debug('picklistValue.GetValue--> ' +picklistValue.getValue());
        system.debug('Value matchs');
        //my code to commit
    } else{
        system.debug('error');
    }
}
```

I am trying to compare every picklist value. but it only hits the first picklist value in Salesforce org. then it comes to the else condition, throwing as an error. how to compare every picklist and commit the changes?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please read [ask]. Right now, it's not very clear what it is you're trying to do. Please [edit] your question to go into greater detail about your overall goal is. Including what you've tried so far is good, but don't focus on explaining it. We need to hear the "what" to understand the issue. Hammering out the "how" comes later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually go through all the values. I'd suggest:

```
Set<String> validValues = new Set<String>();
for(PicklistEntry picklistValue: picklistValues) {
  validValues.add(picklistValue.getValue());
}
if(validValues.contains(otherVal) {
  // Do something cool here
} else {
  throw new IntegrationException('...');
}
```

You can't throw an exception before you've tried every value, so that means having that logic after the first loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I achieved it